# Rewriting a link field to link to 2 different places depending on what's given

Tags: navigation, views

I have a content type which contains a website field of type "link." I am creating a view that should have the title which links to the content for each piece of content, unless a link is provided in the website field - then the title should link there.

This is what I am currently trying:

- title field is hidden
- website field results rewritten so that [title] is the text and it is outputted as a link to [field_website-url].
- website field no results are set to go to: [title]

However, this method is not working. It works when there is actually a website URL specified in the website field, but for all others, clicking on the titles links to ".com/link].

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in trying to use the 'link to original content' in 'no results'.

Try putting the fields in this order with these formats:

- Title - just plain text
- Link to content - raw URL
- Website field - raw URL

Then set *Rewrite Results* to `<a href="[token for website]">[title]</a>`

And set *No Results Behaviour* to `<a href="[token for link raw URL]">[title]</a>`

Note you'll have to find the right token for the links in the *Replacement Patterns* section that shows up when you tick 'Rewrite the output of this field'

Don't use 'Output this field as a link' or the link will apply to the *No Results Behaviour* as well, I think.

Comment: I tried this, and the rewrite results works, but the no results behavior still doesn't. I get 

"view">TITLE" 

(where title is the title) and the word "view" links to 

<sitename>.com/<a href

Comment: I figured it out! Instead of using link for the no results, I used <a href="/node/[nid]">[title]</a> and this works. Your response helped me figure this out though!